# VB.NET - Array of Integers needs to be instantiated, how to?

Tags: vb.net

First try

```
Dim holdValues() As Integer 'Doesn't Work
holdValues(1) = 55
```

Second try

```
Dim holdValues(-1) As Integer 'Gives me Index was outside the bounds of the array.
holdValues(1) = 55
```

I'm trying to do something similar to

```
 Dim myString(-1) As String
```

But apparently this doesn't apply to integer arrays. I don't know what the size of the array will be,  it wont get smaller but it will grow larger.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you add the number to

```
holdValues(x) //x+1 will be size of array
```

so something like this

```
Dim array(2) As Integer
array(0) = 100
array(1) = 10
array(2) = 1
```

you can re-allocate the array to be bigger if needed by doing this.

```
ReDim array(10) as Integer
```

you'll have to add in your code when you should make your array bigger. You can also look into lists. Lists take care of this issue automatically.

here's some info on Lists: http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-vbnet

Hope this helps.

Also a link for general knowledge on arrays http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-vbnet

Comment: Thank you Eric, sorry i gave you -1 i pressed that in error! Good thing i was able to change it.

Comment: thanks, If this was the answer please add the green check mark under the 1. Have a nice one Intrus

Comment: Is there a way to have an array automatically grow in size? It seems possible with Strings, i showed my example above. Is this not possible with integers?

Comment: I would have to say use a list instead of an array. they work a lot like arrays however they are dynamically allocated and therefore grow as needed. I've edited my answer with information about lists.

Comment: Good stuff, thank you again, great sites. I will wait a bit prior to accepting your answer; I always wait a bit to see if i receive other answers. Take care

Comment: Please do use a list instead of using Redim on arrays! ;-)

Comment: Just a small point to be nit-picky, in the first line of code you indicate that x is the size of the array, it is actually the upper bound (as shown in your second code snippet).  The size of the array would be x+1

Answer (score 11):

You could use the Initializers shortcut:

```
Dim myValues As Integer() = New Integer() {55, 56, 67}
```

But if you want to resize the array, etc. then definately have a look at a List(Of Integer):

```
'Initialise the list
Dim myValues As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)

'Shortcut to pre-populate it with known values
myValues.AddRange(New Integer() {55, 56, 57})

'Add a new value, dynamically resizing the array
myValues.Add(32)

'It probably has a method do do what you want, but if you really need an array:
myValues.ToArray()
```